# Cannot boot from Ubuntu Live CD on preinstalled Windows 8 laptop

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, system-installation, windows-8, vaio

I bought a Sony Vaio with Windows 8 yesterday.

I want to install Ubuntu, (latest version), alongside Windows. There is an **assist** button on the laptop to enter the boot option menu, (otherwise, Windows 8 is booted by default.

Whenever I choose the, 'boot from CD' option, it says 'No operating system found'.
CD is valid since I tried it on another computer and it worked fine. I have tried both versions, 12.04 and 12.10.

What is the problem, or how should I install Ubuntu on my laptop?

Comment: Try to create a boot USB with [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) from Win 8.

Comment: disabled `secure boot` ( or UEFI)?

Comment: @Web-E there are two options UEFI (default) and Legacy. Should I choose Legacy?

Comment: Yea legacy.  But first search for secure boot option. See if you can disable it. If not, check whether you can boot windows 8 in legacy mode. You may have to reinstall windows 8. Docs - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI . Also use 64bit ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with samsung notebooks (np55 serie) and pre-installed w8. 
The solution was for myself:

- Bios > Advanced > Fast Boot = Disable
- Bios > Boot > Secure Boot > Disable
- Bios > Boot > Bios mode (under the Secure Boot) > CSM mode

After this modification the laptop will see all my usb device (usb bdrom, usb drive) and able to boot from it.